# Is SharePoint 2016 & SharePoint 2019 supports SQL Server 2017 developer edition as backend SQL Server

Tags: 2016, sql-server, 2019

I have a plan to upgrade our SharePoint 2013 web application to SharePoint 2019 for this task now I am preparing Test Environment for SharePoint 2016 & SharePoint 2019 before that I want to clear some below my confusions:

1. Is SharePoint 2016 & SharePoint 2019 supports SQL Server 2017 developer edition as backend SQL Server because in Production I will mount SharePoint 2019 upgraded database, In production sure it will be SQL Server 2017 Enterprise edition.
2. Can SharePoint 2016 & SharePoint 2019 will support sharing the same instance in a separate SQL Server 2017 Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint 2019 support SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition **only** for non-production use.

**Check also**

- [Supported SQL Server Version for SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/)
- [SQL Server Best Practices for SharePoint 2019](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-best-practices-sharepoint/)

**Update**

If I got your second point correctly, and you want to use the same SQL server instance for multiple farms.

So the answer is **Yes**, but for optimal performance in production environment, you would install SQL Server on a dedicated server that does not run other farm roles and does not host databases for other applications.

Comment: 2.Can SharePoint 2016 & SharePoint 2019 will support to share same instance in separate SQL Server 2017 Server?

Comment: Not clear! what do you mean at this point?

Comment: Hi can i use same SQL Server 2017 instance for Create SharePoint 2016 farm and SharePoint 2019 farm ?

Comment: @user3520155 Yes, you can! please, check the updated answer!

Comment: Thanks can i use in my case also for upgrade SP 2013 to SP 2016 and to SP 2019 ,i want to use separate SQL Server but one SQL 2017 Instance for SP 2016 & SP 2019

Comment: Yes, but SP 2013 doesn't support SQL 2017, check this [SharePoint 2013 supports SQL Server 2014 SP3](https://debug.to/570/sharepoint-2013-supports-sql-server-2014-sp3)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote it in case it helped you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117604/discussion-between-user3520155-and-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp).

Comment: Hi please can tell me can i use same instance for two SharePoint Farms (1.SP 2016, 2nd SP 2019)

Comment: Have you read the answer and comments!!! I answered this point!

Comment: For new questions. please, follow the community rules and stop asking multiple questions in the same thread!! any new query should be added in a new thread! and Don't forget to upvote and mark the helpful answer as accepted!